# Htaccess one and two parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm a newbie in htaccess and I'm having a problem. See my htaccess code below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/lesson/([^/]*)\.htm$ /thesis/index.php?page=$1&lesson=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.htm$ /Thesis/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

When the user click or navigate to a link which is having two parameters. The page is giving the requested page correctly. The URL looks like this `http://www.example.com/home/lesson/1.1.htm`

But after that, when the user click the link which is having one parameter for example is the logout script. everything goes wrong. the URL became `http://www.example.com/home/lesson/logout.htm`

I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have relative URLs and because of the `/`'s in the URL, you're base is messed up. You should either change all your links to absolute URLs, or include the base URI in the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Because the URL you're accessing is: `http://www.example.com/home/lesson/1.1.htm`, and as far as the browser knows, the "page" is `1.1.htm` and the "path" is `/home/lesson/`. Thus, if the browser sees a relative URL (something that doesn't start with an "http" or "/"), it needs to append a base to the beginning in order to properly resolve it. Since the browser thinks the path is `/home/lesson/`, it attaches that to the beginning.

Comment: Thanks Jon Lin, It works.... Now I can proceed to the next module. And it's because of you. Thank a lot...